# Do I have ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 and the about page includes an entry called "ASP.NET Web Frameworks and tools 2013" although there is nothing on there to specifically mention ASP.NET MVC 5 (In the add/remove programs control panel, the only version of ASP.NET listed is 2.0 but I presume that's a red herring).

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC application and look in the references, I see it's referring to System.Web.MVC version 4.0.30319 which I presume is ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

Is this the right way to check which version of ASP.NET MVC a project is actually using? If I am indeed using 4.0, how do I get access to 5.0?

### edit - I was an idiot

Just realised that I had the properties panel sized so that the dll version wasn't being shown on the screen, and I was looking at the runtime version instead. As Anirudha pointed out, the DLL version for asp.net 5.0 is in fact 5.0.

Comment: Look inside the `package.config` there you will find `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. MVC 5 needs .NET 4.5 I think..

Comment: Thanks - it does say 5.0.0 in there :) I was just a bit confused by the fact that the DLL version numbers weren't 5.0

Comment: @Andy You can also check the version of MVC in reference > system.web.mvc right click > properties and it will show you version. useful in case of package file missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in the command console, you will get the latest MVC package.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

You can also look in the NuGet package manager, and look in the drop down for pre-releases.

Comment: Nice, but that does not answer what the OP has asked.

Comment: My bad. I thought that would help to be able to see what version, and then get the version 5 if needed. It is the route I went.   Sorry for the bad answer.  :(  lol